# Artifactory: count of images in docker registry?

Tags: artifactory

I am quite a new user of artifactory and at the moment would like to check the number of docker images in an already existing setup. I have several docker registries in artifactory and would like to automate this check. Is there an api for it maybe?

Thanks for all help :)

BR,
Rafal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) for searching all the `manifest.json` files (since each image has exactly one such file). 
For example (using `curl`):

```
curl -XPOST https://your.artifactory.domain/api/search/aql -T aql.json -u user:pass
```

Where `aql.json` is:

```
items.find({"repo":"docker-local","name":"manifest.json","path":{"$match":"*"}}).include("repo","path","name")
```

The query above searches for all the `manifest.json` files in the `docker-local` repository under any path (match `*`). It returns the following (example):

```
{
  "results" : [ {
    "repo" : "docker-local",
    "path" : "hello-world/latest",
    "name" : "manifest.json"
  }, {
    "repo" : "docker-local",
    "path" : "hello-world/1.0",
    "name" : "manifest.json"
  } ],
  "range" : {
    "start_pos" : 0,
    "end_pos" : 2,
    "total" : 2
  }
}
```

You can take the `range.total` as the number of images.

HTH,
Yinon